# TypeHandler with @MappedJdbcTypes

Tags: java, mybatis

I want to configure a type handler to convert Date columns to LocalDate (Java 8), but I am having trouble registering it. I based my typeHandler on the MyBatis doc and this [project](https://github.com/javaplugs/mybatis-java-time).

Mapper:

```
<resultMap id="clientResult" type="client">
    <id property="id" column="id" />
    <result property="name" column="name" />
    <result property="birthday" column="birthday"  />
</resultMap>
```

Client class:

```
public class Client {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private java.time.LocalDate birthday;
}
```

The type handler:

```
@MappedJdbcTypes(value = JdbcType.DATE)
public class LocalDateHandler extends BaseTypeHandler<java.time.LocalDate> {
    ...
}
```

I get this error on startup:

```
org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing Mapper XML. Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No typehandler found for property birthday
```

After some debugging and experimenting, I found multiple solutions.

#### Solution #1

Remove `@MappedJdbcTypes`

#### Solution #2

Change the `@MappedJdbcTypes` annotation to use the undocumented `includeNullJdbcType = true`

```
@MappedJdbcTypes(value = JdbcType.DATE, includeNullJdbcType = true)
```

#### Solution #3

Add a `jdbcType` to the `resultMap` property:

```
<result property="birthday" column="birthday" jdbcType="DATE" />
```

However, I would have expected everything to work as presented above. What's going on? What should I do?

Note: I use MyBatis 3.3.1

#### update

This is considered a bug for now: https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/issues/591

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java 8 LocalDate mapping with mybatis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25113579/java-8-localdate-mapping-with-mybatis)

Comment: I actually used that question as a reference for my implementation but something is not working with `@MappedJdbcTypes`