# java to sql dates shifted by one day

Tags: java, mysql, mybatis, ibatis

I am using a MyBatis ORM to interact between my Java 11 application and the MySql database. When I want to insert date objects (tried `java.time.LocalDate` and `java.sql.Date`) to the table (column has jdbc type `DATE`), all dates are shifted backwards by 1 day.

Pseudo-Example:

```java
Entry entry1 = new Entry("John", LocalDate.of(2019,4,29))
Entry entry2 = new Entry("John", Date.valueOf("2019-04-29"))
```

Both of these will be stored as follows in the sql table.

```
user  |date       |
------|-----------|
John  |2019-04-28 |
```

The mysql server uses UTC, the application may run on different timezones (GMT+1, GMT+2) but this shouldn't consistently shift dates, should it?

The java class:

```java
public class Entry {
    public String user;
    public LocalDate date;
}
```

The MyBatis mapper and Service:

```java
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Mapper;
import java.util.List;

@Mapper
public interface UserEntryMapper {
    void saveEntry(@Param("entry") Entry entry);
}

public class UserEntryService {
    private final UserEntryMapper userEntryMapper;

    @Inject
    public UserEntryService(UserEntryMapper dbMapper){
        this.userEntryMapper = dbMapper;
    }

    @Transactional
    public void saveEntry(Entry entry) {
        userEntryMapper.saveEntry(entry);
    }
}
```

The MyBatis xml:

```xml
<insert id="saveEntry">
   INSERT INTO `user_entry_list`
   (`user`, `date`)
   VALUES
   (#{entry.user}, #{entry.date, jdbcType=DATE});
</insert>
```

**EDIT:**
I tried instantiating the `java.util.Date` differently:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2019);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.APRIL);
cal.set(Calendar.DATE, 29);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
java.util.Date date = cal.getTime();
```

Indeed, this still results in `2019-04-28`. However, if I put `cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 2)`, then the correct date is saved. This means `java.util.Date` and `LocalDate` are implicitly setting a time at midnight... : /

Comment: Just a quick guess: If the timestamp by "Date.valueOf" is based on the date with 12 AM, a shift to the UTC would be e.g. -1 or -2 hours, which leads to one day off. Instead of 2019-04-29 00:00:00 you will get 2019-04-28 22:00:00

Comment: Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25113579/java-8-localdate-mapping-with-mybatis), it might help you.

Comment: @Enak I suspected something similar. but `java.sql.Date.valueOf()` takes the string representation of a date, not a timestamp. It would be strange if this is converted internally to a timestamp

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, I am using the current version of mybatis which should have support for these classes included (Type handlers for "JSR 310: Date and Time API" has been merged into mybatis core since 3.4.5)

Comment: @Damian Maybe just give it a try. Get your date by using `Date.valueOf` and use `setHours(int i)` to set the value to e.g. 8 AM, insert it into the table and check what happened. AFAIK a java.sql.date is just a wrapper for a timestamp, so it could still be a conversion problem. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html

Comment: @Enak Thanks for the hint, added the test case to the question

Comment: i want you to think about this sentence really hard : "`The mysql server uses UTC, the application may run on different timezones (GMT+1, GMT+2) `"

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `serverTimezone=GMT%2B1` to the JDBC connection URL. e.g.

```
jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test?serverTimezone=GMT%2B1
```

**UPDATE**
This seems like a bug, actually.
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=93444